# jQuery (.scroll function) "bug", scrolling the page "jumps" for like 30px

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

When you scroll down the page for 130px (as i set it and that's the height of the header too), then the new class "f-nav" kicks in, everything is working nicely, except that the page that is under the nav menu, jumps for like 30 pixels, as you can see here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/8M2Vh/2/ 
The "TEXT TEXT" which i typed, the first row almost becomes "invisible" after you scroll for 130 pixels.

```
jQuery("document").ready(function($){

var nav = $('nav');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 130) {
        nav.addClass("f-nav");
    } else {
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");
    }
});
```

});

This is the code that should do this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/8M2Vh/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you set `position:fixed` on `nav` element is taken out off the flow of the document, then the space can be filled by the next element you should need to complement your function with this:

```
var nav = $('nav');
var navh = $('nav').outerHeight();
var mainP = $('#main').css('paddingTop');

$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 130) {
        nav.addClass("f-nav");
        $('#main').css('paddingTop',navh);
   } else {
        nav.removeClass("f-nav");
        $('#main').css('paddingTop',mainP);
    }
});
```

Check this **[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8M2Vh/5/)**

Comment: Well, this works perfectly the way i writed it on the jsfiddle, but when i try to put it to my webpage, it doesn't work anymore, i'm not very good at fixing things (am still learning), but i spended 10 hours+ on that thing before posting it here.

Here's a new fiddle, can you make it work there? I have a div there and a border around, the border still jumps as it did before =/

http://jsfiddle.net/8M2Vh/6/

Comment: @NubCake then use `top` instead of padding to offset the main... since you have that border with box-shadow is the best option just add position:relative on the CSS .. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/8M2Vh/8/

Comment: OMG, thank you! Finally it works, i love you :D
You have no idea how much trouble you saved me, thanks!

Comment: @NubCake np mate glad to help you

Comment: could there be any improvements to this? For example that jquery would get the height automatically? `if ($(this).scrollTop() > 130) {` So this number would be automatically adjusted according to the height the header would be? atm there's a padding "130px" selected to it, but i don't want to get padding number, i want jquery to get height (so that i can add a picture or whatever in the header and it would automatically adjust it).